# Zoom background image in flexbox layout without affecting neighbour elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I've got an layout which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5BaU.jpg) and I'm trying to zoom image-background on hover, but I can't get this effect in any way without affecting neighbour elements (on hover it expands like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPl7J.jpg)) - my aim is to zoom only image and stay inside the parent div element. Is there any workaround for this in flexbox layout? This is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="index-wrapper">
    <nav class="index-menu">
        123
    </nav>
    <main class="index-main">
        <div class="index-square" style="background: yellow;"></div>
        <div class="index-square">
            <div class="index-square-inner" style="background-image: url(assets/img/is-2.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: cover;transition: all .2s ease-in-out;">
                <div style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">
                    123
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="index-square" style="background: pink;">123</div>
        <div class="index-square" style="background: purple;">123</div>
    </main>
</div>
</body>
```

SCSS:

```
.index-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;

  .index-menu {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #d0d0d0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 2em;
  }

  .index-main {
    display: flex;
    background: yellow;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    .index-square {
      flex-basis: 50%;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;

      .index-square-inner {
        flex: 1;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        &:hover {
          transform: scale(1.1);
        }

        div {
          flex: 1;
          width: 100%;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Set `index-square`'s position to relative and `index-square-inner` to absolute with a width/height of 100% and top/left position of 0; Should get the zoom without trying to expand its parent.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't do the work :( it looks then like [this](https://imgur.com/a/0Soc3)

Comment: Like zgood's answer use `overflow: hidden;` - I forgot to add it in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.index-square` style definition;

```
.index-square {
      flex-basis: 50%;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
       overflow: hidden; /*Add this here*/
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbrg6utb/1/).

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much